# to print all the strings containing a specified sub string

Tags: c++, c

I am a beginner in c ++ .  I am trying to implement a small c ++ code for fun .

The program reads its input from a text file which contains names of all my friends.

The aim of the program is to return / print all the names beginning with a specified letter / nick name

For example

```
Nick 
Joseph
Jack
Robert 
Paul 
David
```

If I input   'J' the result should be Joseph and Jack

and if I input 'P' or 'pa' the result should be paul

Can any one please guide me to get the logic right.  Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: you've already got the basic logic set. You just need to a) prompt for input b) accept input c) search your strings for the input d) report on the results.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


ifstream input;

input.open("words.txt") ;

char word[80] ;

char output;


if (input.fail())
{
cout << " the file doesnt exist" <<endl;
cout << " exit program" << endl;

return 0 ;

}

while ( !input.eof())
{

input >> output;

cout << output ;

}

input.close() ;

return 0 ;

}

Comment: This above code returns all the names on the screen ! How ever , thats not what i want , i want to provide a means where the user can specify a character or substring like "rob" / "dav"  which should then return the names   Robert and David respectively .  any help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ths **logic** goes like this:

```
read the desired prefix from user
repeat
  read one line from file
  if the line starts with the desired prefix print it
until there are no more lines
```

Comment: #include <iostream> #include <fstream> using namespace std; int main() { ifstream input; input.open("words.txt") ; char word[80] ; char output; if (input.fail()) { cout << " the file doesnt exist" <<endl; cout << " exit program" << endl; return 0 ; } while ( !input.eof()) { input >> output; cout << output ; } input.close() ; return 0 ; }

Comment: Hi @Michael ,  Thanks a lot for the Logic .   How do i use the for loop to scan every line in the text file for the desired input from the user ? pls help ! can you probably guide me with the code please ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
  ifstream input; 
  input.open("words.txt");
  char word[80];
  char output;

  if (input.fail()) 
  { 
    cout << " the file doesnt exist" << endl;
    cout << " exit program" << endl; 

    return 0 ; 
  } 

  while ( !input.eof() ) 
  { 
    input >> output; 
    cout << output; 
  } 
  input.close();

  return 0; 
}
```